# How do you run pre-written lldb commands?

Tags: debugging, lldb

I have this file with lldb commands in it that I want to run.
Is there a way to run pre-written lldb commands?

Answer (score 4):

lldb's help system is a good way to answer this sort of question:

```
(lldb) help command
     Commands for managing custom LLDB commands.

Syntax: command <subcommand> [<subcommand-options>]

The following subcommands are supported:

      alias   -- Define a custom command in terms of an existing command.  Expects 'raw' input (see 'help raw-input'.)
      delete  -- Delete one or more custom commands defined by 'command regex'.
      history -- Dump the history of commands in this session.
                 Commands in the history list can be run again using "!<INDEX>".   "!-<OFFSET>" will re-run the command that is <OFFSET> commands from the end of the list (counting the current command).
      regex   -- Define a custom command in terms of existing commands by matching regular expressions.
      script  -- Commands for managing custom commands implemented by interpreter scripts.
      source  -- Read and execute LLDB commands from the file <filename>.
      unalias -- Delete one or more custom commands defined by 'command alias'.

For more help on any particular subcommand, type 'help <command> <subcommand>'.
```

`command source` looks promising:

```
(lldb) help command source 
     Read and execute LLDB commands from the file <filename>.

Syntax: command source <cmd-options> <filename>

Command Options Usage:
  command source [-e <boolean>] [-c <boolean>] [-s <boolean>] <filename>

       -c <boolean> ( --stop-on-continue <boolean> )
            If true, stop executing commands on continue.

       -e <boolean> ( --stop-on-error <boolean> )
            If true, stop executing commands on error.

       -s <boolean> ( --silent-run <boolean> )
            If true don't echo commands while executing.

     This command takes options and free-form arguments.  If your arguments resemble option specifiers (i.e., they start with a - or --), you must use ' -- ' between the end of the command options and the beginning of the arguments.
```

There's also an `apropos` command that will search for keywords in the help.  Unfortunately `apropos command` returns too many hits to be particularly helpful in your case.  `apropos file` is a little less noisy, but just looking at the command subcommands is probably easiest.  `help` with no arguments will list the top level commands which might also help you get started.

Note, you can also tell lldb to source a random file of commands when you launch it from the command line (with the `-s` option).  To find out more about lldb's command line options, run:

```
 > lldb --help
```